# Difference between AmE and BrE usage of "piss off".

Tags: american-english, british-english

[Piss](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/piss) and a lot of derived expressions ([piss about/around](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/piss%20about), [piss down](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/piss%20down)) are all marked as British English. [Piss off](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/piss%20off) is however not labelled as such.

Is *piss off* used in American English? How does it differ from the BrE usage?

Comment: You say that "piss off" is not labelled as BrE. But in fact, the dictionary you cite reads "*British sometimes vulgar* :  to leave immediately :  SCRAM —usually used as a command".  In AmE **piss off** means to cause someone to get angry or irritated.

Comment: As an AmE speaker, I associate "piss off" very strongly with BrE. In AmE I hear "fuck off" (vulgar) or "get lost" (not vulgar) far more often than "piss off". It could be regional though.

Comment: Not directly answering your question, but [this ELU page](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/500658/how-did-pissed-come-to-mean-drunk-or-angry) does actually touch on it and is an interesting read.

Answer (score 4):

I can't speak for American usage. But in British usage, people say "To piss somebody off" = "to annoy them".

In the passive, "pissed off" means angry. [I have heard Americans use "pissed" in this way. This is now recognised here because of American films and TV, but when I was younger, that only meant "drunk".]

"Piss off" as a intransitive phrase (usually as a vulgar command) is quite different - it may indicate that the speaker is angry, but it doesn't mean "annoy somebody".